# How to create a series of questions without waiting for a users reply in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently trying to create a quiz bot in discord but I couldn't seem to find a way to send a series of questions that does not require a users reply. Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def ask(ctx):

    _list = [
    'question_1', 
    'question_2']

    list1 = random.choice(_list)

    answer = "default"
    hint = "default1"
    if _list[0] == list1:
        answer = "1"
        hint = "one"
    else: 
        answer = "2"
        hint = "two"

    await ctx.send("What is the answer to this question?")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(list1)
    def check(m): return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=None)

    if msg.content == answer:
        await ctx.send("good")
    else:
        await ctx.send("What is the answer to this question? hint:" + hint)
        await ctx.send(list1)
        def check(m): return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=None)
        if msg.content == answer:
            await ctx.send("good")
        else: 
            await ctx.send("wrong.")
```

This is the concept that I am currently using. Note that this whole code works, I just want to find a way to send the question with a hint (`await ctx.send("What is the answer to this question?" + hint)`) after a specific amount of time after the first question. I know that the main part of the problem is i'm using `await client.waitfor` , but I have no idea what to change it with or how to edit it. Thanks!

Sorry if the answer is supposed to be obvious or if my code is too messy, I'll be willing to answer any questions asked. I guess the main reason I haven't found a solution yet is because I can't seem to explain properly while searching xP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'timeout' to register if the user hasn't answered in a while, in this case I'll be using 60 seconds.
Then, when the 60 seconds end, you edit the old message, but this time, including the hint:

```py
    question_message = await ctx.send("What is the answer to this question?") #save the old message to be edited later, so you can inlcude the hint later
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(list1)
    def check(m): return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel
    try:
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60)#60 seconds timeout
    except asyncio.TimeoutError: #try+except to get when the timeout is over
        def check_timeout(m):
            if m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel and m.content != answer:#edit this check to not let through wrong answers, but sending a message if the answer is wrong
                m.channel.send("wrong")
            return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel and m.content != answer
        await question_message.edit(content="What is the answer to this question? Hint:" +hint)#edit the old message to include the hint
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_timeout)

    if msg.content == answer:
        await ctx.send("good")
    else:
        await ctx.send("What is the answer to this question? hint:" + hint)
        await ctx.send(list1)
        def check(m): return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=None)
        if msg.content == answer:
            await ctx.send("good")
        else: 
            await ctx.send("wrong.")
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Chuaat ! I tried your code but it seems an error seems to come up every time I answer after 60 seconds, `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'msg' referenced before assignment`. Also, my main codes will be using videos and images as questions so I don't think this is what I was looking for, but I'll be glad if you provide only a solution to the error and I'll figure out myself what to pass after except. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I forgot one `msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)` in the except, I edited it and this should work now. @MarioArquette

Comment: All right its functioning perfectly, the message edits after the given timeout with no errors. But once I send a wrong answer before the timeout, it immediately sends what comes after the else statement. Is there any way to have the command disregard wrong answers? Thanks @Chuaat !

Comment: So do you want to only go in the else if the time from the timeout is over? @MarioArquette

Comment: Yessir something like that. Is there a way? @Chuaat

Comment: I used another check to only catch messages if they are the right answer. I hope it's what you wanted. @MarioArquette

Comment: I think I understand what you did but this error seems to pop up : `SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function` for the line after `if m.author` and i'm not sure what to do to fix it. @Chuaat thanks!

Comment: You can just remove the `await`, like I did in my code.

Comment: All right @Chuaat, I tried it immediately and its working as intended, thank you so much~!